# How to open/find the file created by path_provider?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

I'm a beginner at flutter and dart and had some issues with file handling using flutter.

I'm trying to store data locally in text files for my flutter application, and came across the standard tutorial on flutter's website which used path_provider and dart:io. It had instructions on getting the path and reading and writing to a file, however this didn't seem to work for files I added to the project. The only way to store to files was to first write using the inbuilt functions, then reading this newly created file. I can't add my own file and read it using flutter.

I also can't open the file created by flutter as I don't know where its stored. The path given by `getApplicationDocumentsDirectory()` returns the path `/data/user/0/com.example.daily_challenges/app_flutter`, and I don't know where to find this in my project.

In summary: How do I read a pre-existing file and how do I view the file created automatically by flutter.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 5):

You can access the files from a physical device or simulator through Device File Explorer in Android Studio. Follow [this guide](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/device-file-explorer)

Comment: The Guide was very useful for me. It helped me to browse saved files on the device.

Answer (score 3):

You won't be able to access getApplicationDocumentsDirectory().
If you are using android device, you can try to store it in getExternalStorageDirectory(). There's no equivalent in IOS though.

Comment: Ah ok, thanks! Is there a way to add and read my own text files?

Comment: to read and write file, flutter has provided you with a [cookbook](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/persistence/reading-writing-files).


What do you mean by add? If it is to download the file and store it, you can check out [dio](https://pub.dev/packages/dio) or [http](https://pub.dev/packages/http) package in pub.dev. There are also many pages on Google describe about how to download file and store it.

Comment: Add as in use a premade CSV file in my app.

Answer (score 1):

If you are running in a physical device. Open Device File Explorer in Android Studio  and you can find the file under
data/data/your app package/app_flutter/fileName.txt

For example,
data/data/com.example.file_example/app_flutter/example.txt

And if you want to read the pre-existing file, you not need to anything specific, if you give the same file name, if not exist, it will create one, otherwise it will return the old one.

```
final File file = File(filePath);
file.writeAsStringSync('${text}', mode: FileMode.append);
```

For write, you consider using FileMode if you want to append text to the existing file. Or else by default overwrite will happen.

For read, you can consider this

```
final File file = File(filePath);
String text = await file.readAsString();
```

Answer (score 1):

For IOS you should add the below code to your `info.plist` file (in ios/runner)

```
<key>LSSupportsOpeningDocumentsInPlace</key>
<true/>
<key>UIFileSharingEnabled</key>
<true/>
```

after that you can use `getApplicationDocumentsDirectory()` and save your file in storage.

Answer (score 0):

Just use Device File Explorer from Android Studio.

But the weird thing, `path_provider` gives you path like `/data/user/0/your_app_id/...`, but in fact all files are located in `/data/data/your_app_id/...`, as mentioned in previous answer.