# How do I access /data/user/0/ folder from Android?

Tags: android, flutter

I am currently trying to access the `/data/user/0/` folder. The problem is that I cannot seem to find it. I am using the [path_provider](https://pub.dev/packages/path_provider) package.

Where can I locate this folder?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63769816/how-to-open-find-the-file-created-by-path-provider ?

Answer (score 4):

In Android Studio go to the Device Manager, select a device & then in the Device Explorer you can click through to any directories that doesn't require root access.

To see your database file, go to `/data/data/com.example.<APP_NAME>/databases`.

Ignore trying to view your db via the `/data/user/0/` path as this is root user restricted.

[image]

If you want to see the table in your device's db then you should use Android Studio's App Inspection tool
[image]

Answer (score 2):

for my real device i found the files in:

> C:\Users<userName>\AppData\Local\Google\AndroidStudio2023.1\device-explorer\Xiaomi
> Redmi Note 9S_\data\data\com.\files

I hope to be helpful

Answer (score 0):

check this flutter plugin, but works on android only https://pub.dev/packages/ext_storage

Answer (score 0):

There is a file manager called FX with the option of viewing system files, including :system/data
However, the access to system/data/user is denied because it requires root permission. All the other directories in system/data are accessible on Android 10.

[system folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YkaBx.jpg)

[system/data folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qkoIp.jpg)

[system/data/user folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k4tpb.jpg)